# Specify hover colours directly in customized Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, customization

I'm using a custom build of Bootstrap 4.5.3 with some fairly simple changes.

Here's my custom SCSS:

```
$newcolor1: #00a89c;
$newcolor2: #e61b53;

$colors: (
    "newcolor1": $newcolor1,
    "newcolor2": $newcolor2
);

$primary:   $newcolor1;

$theme-colors: (
    "primary": $primary,
    "newcolor2": $newcolor2
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

I'm adding two new colours, setting "primary" to be newcolor1, and adding a theme for newcolor2 so that I can do e.g. btn-newcolor2.

Bootstrap automatically calculates variants of these colours for use with hover, focus, etc, which look fine to me, but my client wants to specify the hover colours directly and that has taken me beyond my very limited Sass knowledge.

Looking through the source files, it seems as though Bootstrap darkens the base colour by a fixed percentage to create the hover version. Is there a way that I could force it to use a specific colour for .btn-primary:hover and .btn-newcolor2:hover? The ideal would be if I could get it to use the specified colour where I have provided one, and use the default behaviour (darkening by a fixed percentage) where I haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mixin used to generate the button `css` colour states is called `button-variant()` which is located in `bootstrap/scss/mixins`.

This sass mixin does have the parameter capability for handling custom `.btn` hover and active colour states...

```scss
@mixin button-variant(
  $background, 
  $border, 
  $hover-background: darken($background, 7.5%), 
  $hover-border: darken($border, 10%),
  $active-background: darken($background, 10%),
  $active-border: darken($border, 12.5%)
) { 
  //...
}
```

But as you can see the hover and active params are `$default:` params using [sass colour darken() function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#darken) as values to calculate the passed `$theme-colors` colour value to automatically generate colours for the states.

This makes it impossible to handle button state colours by just using `$theme-colors`.

---

> There are a few ways to customise the `.btn` active and hover state
> colours whilst minimising compiled `css` and avoiding
> duplicate/overriding selectors in compiled `css` output.

### First method (easiest)

See `scss` below which handles bootstrap vendor `@imports` individually and handling custom `vars` and `map-removals` in the correct order, so bootstrap compiles and uses variables correctly.

Follow comments in the `scss` so you know what is happening...

```scss
// import initial bootstrap vendors

@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// remove unused default bootstrap colours from bs colour maps to prevent larger compiled css file sizes
// this will also speed up compiling time as you are not generating css for all bootstrap standard colours
// if you wish to keep some standard bootstrap colours then remove the ones you want to keep from the map-remove lists below

$colors: map-remove($colors, "blue","indigo","purple","pink","red","orange","yellow","green","teal","cyan","white","gray","gray-dark");
$grays: map-remove($grays, "100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800","900");
$theme-colors: map-remove($theme-colors, "primary","secondary","success","danger","warning","info","light","dark");

// use sass @debug to check dump logs of your colour maps after modifying them if you wish...

// @debug $colors;
// @debug $grays;
// @debug $theme-colors;

// now add your custom colour variables

$new-color-1: #00a89c;
$new-color-2: #e61b53;

// now add your custom colour maps using above variables

$colors: (
  "newcolor1": $new-color-1,
  "newcolor2": $new-color-2
);

// you can always tidy this up by including these variables and any other bootstrap theming override variables into a separate sass _vars.scss file
// and then import _vars.scss here (before root.scss and after mixins.scss|map-removals)...

//@import "./vars";

// now import the rest of your needed bootstrap scss vendor files below this
// the below imports will now use any variable overrides you've defined above

// if you want to reduce you css output file size and speed up compiling
// you can remove unused scss vendor imports below, for example i've removed breadcrumb, toasts and carousel

@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/card";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/media";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/close";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/popover";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/print";
```

Because we emptied the `$theme-colors` map, bootstrap will not compile `@each` loops which utilise `$theme-colors` because it is now empty.

We can now manually use `button-variant()` mixin inside any `.btn-*` selector to create custom buttons without add extra css to the compiled output.

This option is easiest because you can pass any colour you wish to the `button-variant()` params.

```scss
.btn-primary {
  @include button-variant(
    $new-color-1, // background
    $new-color-1, // border
    $new-color-1, // hover background (customise how you wish)
    $new-color-1, // hover border (customise how you wish)
    $new-color-1, // active background (customise how you wish)
    $new-color-1 // active border (customise how you wish)
  );
}

.btn-secondary {
  @include button-variant(
    $new-color-2, // background
    $new-color-2, // border
    $new-color-2, // hover background (customise how you wish)
    $new-color-2, // hover border (customise how you wish)
    $new-color-2, // active background (customise how you wish)
    $new-color-2 // active border (customise how you wish)
  );
}
```

---

### Second method (trickier)

Using the above code, re-introduce `$theme-colors` and modify/override the `@include button-variant()` in `mixins.scss`.

*Removed the custom button selectors from the above code before continuing.*

This method is trickier to precisely control hover and active state colours because `@include button-variant()` will use the same param `scss` colour adjustments for each passed colour.

You can try this... re-introduce `$theme-colors` before `root.scss` and immediately after `$colors` map array.

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": $new-color-1,
  "secondary": $new-color-2
);
```

Then create an overriding button mixin to handle all button variant calls.

Add this bootstrap v4.5.3 modified button-variant mixin after our `@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";` and before the `map-removals`.

You can put this in a sass file called `_mixins.scss` in your project and import like this `@import "./mixins";` to keep things tidy.

You can also keep all your custom mixins for this project in "./mixins" too.

Now we can modify the custom `@mixin button-variant()` parameters to handle passed `$theme-colors`.

```scss
// i've customised params in the button-variant() mixin below as an example
// see original default mixin params as comments below

// $background
// $border
// $hover-background: darken($background, 7.5%)
// $hover-border: darken($border, 10%) 
// $active-background: darken($background, 10%)
// $active-border: darken($border, 12.5%)

@mixin button-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $hover-background: lighten($background, 10%),
  $hover-border: lighten($border, 10%),
  $active-background: lighten($background, 2.5%),
  $active-border: lighten($border, 2.5%)
) {
  color: color-yiq($background);
  @include gradient-bg($background);
  border-color: $border;
  @include box-shadow($btn-box-shadow);

  @include hover() {
    color: color-yiq($hover-background);
    @include gradient-bg($hover-background);
    border-color: $hover-border;
  }

  &:focus,
  &.focus {
    color: color-yiq($hover-background);
    @include gradient-bg($hover-background);
    border-color: $hover-border;
    @if $enable-shadows {
      @include box-shadow($btn-box-shadow, 0 0 0 $btn-focus-width rgba(mix(color-yiq($background), $border, 15%), .5));
    } @else {
      // Avoid using mixin so we can pass custom focus shadow properly
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 $btn-focus-width rgba(mix(color-yiq($background), $border, 15%), .5);
    }
  }

  // Disabled comes first so active can properly restyle
  &.disabled,
  &:disabled {
    color: color-yiq($background);
    background-color: $background;
    border-color: $border;
    // Remove CSS gradients if they're enabled
    @if $enable-gradients {
      background-image: none;
    }
  }

  &:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
  &:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
  .show > &.dropdown-toggle {
    color: color-yiq($active-background);
    background-color: $active-background;
    @if $enable-gradients {
      background-image: none; // Remove the gradient for the pressed/active state
    }
    border-color: $active-border;

    &:focus {
      @if $enable-shadows and $btn-active-box-shadow != none {
        @include box-shadow($btn-active-box-shadow, 0 0 0 $btn-focus-width rgba(mix(color-yiq($background), $border, 15%), .5));
      } @else {
        // Avoid using mixin so we can pass custom focus shadow properly
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 $btn-focus-width rgba(mix(color-yiq($background), $border, 15%), .5);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This has been enormously useful. I really appreciate your help.